# Adding multiple items to OS Commerce cart programmatically / with API

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, oscommerce

I am creating a custom paintball marker configurator. The customers will be able to choose a marker, then add hundreds of different accessories with our html5 / java script configurator. The client has an OSCommerce site and the goal is to send all the pieces that make up their custom marker to the OScommerce cart.

All the pieces in the configurator will be in the oscommerce system, but we're going to build the configurator on codeigniter and a seperate html5 site. So my question is, is there any way to send information from another page on his site (our configurator) to the oscommerce cart.

I was thinking maybe an array of products with their specific information like sku number, product id, etc, and add that array to the oscommerce cart.

Any ideas? I can't find any solutions online. Thanks ahead of time!!!

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/45279-add-to-cart-from-external-page-or-site/

https://www.google.com/search?q=oscommerce+add+to+cart+from+external+site+site:forums.oscommerce.com

Looks like a nightmare TBH. Lots of issues with cookies/sessions. Might have to create a separate oscommerce file (e.g. `custom_add_to_cart.php`) to hit from the external page. Doesn't look like there's an easy way to `add to cart > edit options on external page > save to cart`. May be able to avoid some issues if you serve the html5 site on the same domain or create a custom page/module (if oscommerce has those).

Good luck!